# Implement pure virtual function using parent class clode

Tags: c++

In the following simplified example, I was trying to implement a function (from an interface) with the already existing implementation of a parent.
I was wondering if someone could explain why this does not work and if there is a simple work around.

```
using namespace std;

struct IInterface
{
  virtual void vFunction () = 0;
};

struct Base
{
  void vFunction () { }
};

struct A: public Base, public IInterface
{
  using Base::vFunction;
  //virtual void vFunction() { Base::vFunction(); } // Is this the only way to reuse Base code?
};

int main ()
{    
  A a;
  IInterface *pInterface = &a;

  a.vFunction();

  pInterface->vFunction();

  return 0;
}
```

Error is :

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:21:9: error: cannot declare variable 'a' to be of abstract type 'A'
       A a;
         ^
main.cpp:13:12: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'A':
     struct A: public Base, public IInterface
            ^
main.cpp:5:20: note:    virtual void IInterface::vFunction()
       virtual void vFunction () = 0;
                    ^
```

Comment: You already have the solution, what else do you need?

Comment: You kind of already answered your own question in one of you comment below!

Answer (score 1):

`vFunction` in `base` has no relation to `vFunction` in `IInterface`. Because of that, there is no way compiler can use one instead of the other automatically. Your forwarding code is the only way to do this.

Comment: Actually another and better way would be for `Base` to inherit from `IInterface`

Comment: @Slava no argument here, but I imagine, OP had their reasons not to.

Comment: I hardly see any reason.

Comment: @Slava I believe, questions should be taken on the face value, unless they don't make sense. It is conceivable that OP has a third-party class which implements some of the functions of their interface and wants to use them.

Comment: Third-party class has a method whose signature is guaranteed to match one in `IInterface`. Are you serious?

Comment: @Slava sure. Why not? `IInterface` could be specifically designed to match function signatures in the class... In case you don't know, this is how, for example, Go works.